# Como fazer um input para aceitar somente letras?

Tags: javascript, html, css, formulário

Estou fazendo um formulario e o usuario tem que digitar somente letras no campo do nome dele, eu quero bloquear para ele digitar algum outro tipo de caractere ah nao ser as letras, como faço?
Estou programando com HTML5 e CSS 3.
O formulario vai ser WEB.

Comment: Você está fazendo isso em Web, Desktop em que linguagem? Edite sua pergunta para não ser negativado..

Comment: Que browsers queres suportar? Que liguagem estás a usar?

Comment: Por favor não juntes partes de respostas para incluir na pergunta. Junta o código que tens mas sem modificar a pergunta com pedaços de respostas.

Answer (score 4):

Olá, você pode utilizar o Jquery para efetuar isso ou utilizar o javascript sem ele.

Exemplo com jQuery, não precisa mecher no `input`, apenas estar entre as tags `<script></script>`

```
$("#exemplo").on("input", function(){
  var regexp = /[^a-zA-Z]/g;
  if(this.value.match(regexp)){
    $(this).val(this.value.replace(regexp,''));
  }
});
```

Sem jQuery:

No input vai ter que utilizar um evento tipo:

```
<input id="exemplo" onkeypress="return lettersOnly(event);"/>
```

Função  entre as tags `<script></script>` no fim do código

```
function lettersOnly(evt) {
    evt = (evt) ? evt : event;
    var charCode = (evt.charCode) ? evt.charCode : ((evt.keyCode) ? evt.keyCode :
        ((evt.which) ? evt.which : 0));
    if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 65 || charCode > 90) &&
        (charCode < 97 || charCode > 122)) {
        alert("Enter letters only.");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Sim eu estou usando jquery.
Vou testar aqui com jquery!

Comment: Eu testei aqui pra fazer com jquery irei enviar uma parte do meu codigo para voce ver...

Comment: Confira ai e me ajude se possivel eu tenho que fazer o input text aceitar somente letras.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/71ufqe34/1/ Dá uma olhada

Comment: Toma cuidado com o uso do patter pois de acordo com o [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_pattern.asp) ele não suporta alguns navegadores antigos nem no safari, e isto é um sério problema.

Comment: Ta bom muito obrigado! vou conferir..

Comment: Infelizmente não deu certo sera oque é?

Comment: Aparece erro no console ou nada?

Comment: Não aparece, meu codigo js ficou assim:  $("#nome").on("input", function () {
                var regexp = /[^a-zA-Z]/g;
                if ($(this).val().match(regexp)) {
                    $(this).val($(this).val().replace(regexp, ''));
                }
            });

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42555/discussion-between-gustavo-tinoco-and-user49744).

Answer (score 3):

Vou fazer um exemplo em `javascript`puro.

Utilizando expressões regulares.

```html
<form name="form_name" action="recebe_form.php" method="post">
    Name:
    <input id="input_nome" type="text" name="fname">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="valida_nome()">
</form>
<script>
    function valida_nome() {
        var filter_nome = /^([a-zA-Zà-úÀ-Ú]|\s+)+$/;
        if (!filter_nome.test(document.getElementById("input_nome").value)) {
            document.getElementById("input_nome").value = '';
            document.getElementById("input_nome").placeholder = "Nome inválido";
            document.getElementById("input_nome").style.borderColor = "#ff0000";
            document.getElementById("input_nome").style.outline = "#ff0000";
            document.getElementById("input_nome").focus();
            document.getElementById("input_nome").onkeydown = function keydown_nome() {
                document.getElementById("input_nome").placeholder = "";
                document.getElementById("input_nome").style.borderColor = "#999999";
                document.getElementById("input_nome").style.outline = null;
            }
            return false;
        } else {
            document.getElementById("input_nome").value = '';
            document.getElementById("input_nome").placeholder = "Nome Válido";
        }
        return true;
    }

</script>
```

Dessa forma esta aceitando letras,letras acentuadas e espaços.

É aconselhável realizar a validação no banco de dados também.

Segue um exemplo simples em `php`.

recebe_form.php

```
<?php

$name = "";

if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
    if(empty($_POST["nome_cad"])){
        return false;
    }else{
        $nome = htmlspecialchars($_POST["input_nome"]);
        if(!preg_match("/^([a-zA-Zà-úÀ-Ú]|\s+)+$/",$nome)){
            return false; 
    }
}
?>
```